# Java Concordance Exercise

Tags: java, regex, hashtable

So I have a programming exercise that involves concordance.  I am attempting to take a .txt file, use regex to parse it into strings containing all words, then create a Hashtable that has the key (the word) and the value (the number of times the word appears in the document).  We are supposed to be able to account for both case sensitive and non-case sensitive scenarios by passing in a boolean.

Here is what I have:

```
    public Concordance( String pathName, boolean is_case_sensitive ) {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(pathName);
    try {
        file = new Scanner(new File(pathName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No File Found");
    }

    String[] words;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W+");

    words = pattern.split(file.nextLine());
    String[] wordsCopy = new String[words.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        wordsCopy[i] = new String(words[i]);
    }

    int counter = 0;

    while (file.hasNext()){
        for (String w : words){
            counter = 0;
            for (String w2 : wordsCopy){
                if (is_case_sensitive == false){
                    if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(w2)){
                        counter++;
                        //w2 = null;
                        tableOfWords.put(w, counter);
                        file.next();
                    }
                }
                if (is_case_sensitive == true){
                    if (w.equals(w2)){
                        counter++;
                        //w2 = null;
                        tableOfWords.put(w, counter);
                        file.next();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To walk you through where I am and where my error I believe is....

I use the scanner to "take in" the file the use the regex \W+ to get all of words.  I create a String array, I split the Pattern pattern into the String array.  Then I create a deep copy of the array to use during comparison.  (So I now have two String arrays - words and wordsCopy).  I use an int counter variable to keep track of how many times it appears and address case sensitivity by using an if statement and the equals/equalsIgnoreCase methods.  I have been going back and forth between assigning w2 to null (its currently commented out) as I intuitively feel like if it is not set to null, it will be counted twice, but I can't seem to think through it appropriately.  I think I am counting items in duplicate, but can't seem to figure out a solution.    Any insight?  Thanks!

Comment: Not that it matters here but don't use `if (condition == true)` or `if (condition == false)` because you are risking making mistake like `if (condition = true)` - notice that `=` is assigning `==` is comparison. Instead you should use `if(condition)` or `if(!condition)`.

Comment: `\W+` matches strings of non-word characters.  Did you mean to use `\w+` instead?

Comment: Good tip.  Only about 4-5 months into java, so love tips like this.  Thanks!

Comment: Well I am splitting at non-words.  My string arrays seem to be populating correctly, so I think that is working correctly.  Its the loops where I am doing the comparison where I believe my problem is.

Comment: Any particular reason that you're doing this work in your constructor as opposed to another method?

Comment: You are not comparing the words from file. All you are doing is comparing the first line only. you are not reading word like w = file.next(); or i may be mis understood your qustion

Comment: @Makoto - assignment requirements told us to do the work in the constructor.

Comment: Are you just counting words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need any extra String[] to check case sensitive

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W+");
        HashMap<String, AtomicInteger> tableOfWords = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

        while (file.hasNextLine()){
            words = pattern.split(file.nextLine());
            for (String w : words){
                String tmp = w;
                if (!is_case_sensitive){
                    tmp = String.valueOf(w.toLowerCase());
                }

                AtomicInteger count = tableOfWords.get(tmp);
                if (count == null){
                    count = new AtomicInteger(0);
                }
                count.incrementAndGet();
                tableOfWords.put(tmp,count);
            }
        }
```

Convert the actual word into low / high case if case sensitive is not required. then everything work perfectly.

Comment: That seems to be working, but I am encountering an issue in now performing operations on the hashmap such as getting a value or returning keys that match a value.  I've never used the AtomicInteger class before, but it looks to be quite useful, however, it does not appear to allow me to cast from AtomicInteger to int or Integer...is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can use count.intValue(); ( AtomicInteger.intValue()) to get the number of value as int. i have used AtomicInteger so that i can increment with the same instance ( Mutable) . Integer is immutable. so you have to create new Integer each time you want to modify

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are actually counting words multiple times (more than twice aswell)

I'll give you a simple foreach loop to explain what you're doing,
some of the syntax might be wrong as i'm not using an ide to write this code

```
int[5] ints = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[5] intcopy = ints;

for(int i:ints){
  for(int j: intcopy){
    system.out.println(j);
  }
}
```

What you will end out printing is
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5

So instead of counting 5 things you are counting 25 things, hope this helps